# How to disable listitem onCreate in android

Tags: android, listview, oncreate, listitem

Is there any way to disable particular list item in android and enable it on particular conditions onCreate ?? This is dire need for my requirement but i do not see any answers for it on stackoverflow. I have done many operations onItemClick but that is not the actual thing i am looking for, it has to be onCreate at the time when screen is focused. If anyone has come across please share the ideas n codelets..

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not cleare. Post some code. In what condition you want to disable or enable list item? put that conditions in swithch case and call it from onCreate(),call your method from switch case to enable or disable your list item.

Answer (score 0):

u can overwrite the view's ontouch method in the adapter,u will never receive the lietItem's method.

Answer (score 0):

this trick might work for you. get item which you want to disable after populating listview

disable

```
View view = listview.getChildAt(itemPostion);
view.setEnabled(false);
```

enable

```
View view = listview.getChildAt(itemPostion);
view.setEnabled(true);
```

**EDIT**

Another Way- Do it in getView() of Adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) viewDashboard
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.row_dashboard, parent, false);

    if(position==something){
         convertView.setEnabled(false);
     }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: But how can i use this is onCreate ?

Comment: which item do you want to disable ?

Comment: okay...let me try in getView...But i guess right method is setEnabled (setEnable) won't work for convertView

Comment: what is viewDashoard ? My eclipse is unable to identify this variable ? Do i have to define it ?

Comment: it context or activity which you pass to adapter in contructor

Comment: Alright...I got the case...I am getting proper logs for proper condition but for some reason setEnable won't disable that list item...If i click it will still be enabled....Any other properties to try ?

Answer (score 0):

store the positions of item which you want to disable in an array, and when you click on that particular item don't do anything or if you want to give disability feel on UI part then in get view method itself you can do on those particular positions, try it, this should work